# Pulling data from Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull specific data from a PHP multidimensional array.

Array is like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Item Code Number
            [1] => Item Name
            [2] => Item Description
            [3] => MSRP
            [4] => Cost
            [5] => Weight Pounds
            [6] => Weight Kgs
            [7] => Category 1
            [8] => Category 2
            [9] => Category 3
            [10] => Category 4
            [11] => Youtube Link
            [12] => Large Image URL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Amazing Magic Set
            [2] => Easy to learn magic tricks
            [3] => 24.95
            [4] => 10.5
            [5] => 0.95
            [6] => 0.43
            [7] => New Items
            [8] => Tricks
            [9] => *New Tricks*
            [10] => All Tricks
            [11] => blank
            [12] => http://www.magicmakersinc.com/images/product/large/0051.jpg
        )
)
```

What I want to do it loop through the array and pull keys, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6 from each entry and display that data.

This is what I've tried to use:

```
$keys = (array_keys($csv));             
for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($csv); $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($keys[$row] as $key => $value) {
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

I can't get this to display anything.

I've also tried:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($csv); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($csv[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        echo "<td>".$value(0)."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($csv); $row++) {
echo "<tr>";
    foreach($csv[$row] as $key => $value) {
        if($k == '0' || $k == '1' || $k == '2' || $k == '4' || $k == '6'){
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Also take advice for future - don't use multidimensinal arrays for purpose like that - because they should be used just for data which nature can be identified with multidimensional arrays (as calculations on matrices for example). For usage like that - use objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code:

```
foreach ($row ar $val) {
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($val as $k => $v) {
            if($k == '0' || $k == '1' || $k == '2' || $k == '4' || $k == '6'){
                echo "<td>".$td."</td>";
            }
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. *PLEASE* go fix every one of your answers where you said "try this" without any explanation of what was done. Do it today.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `foreach`:

```
foreach ($row ar $tr) {
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($tr as $td) {
            echo "<td>".$td."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: If specific keys needed, add `if` to second `foreach` like:
`if(in_array($tr, [0, 1, 2, 4, 6])) echo ...`

Comment: Using the if in_array is much cleaner than a huge OR block :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming = have

```
$myArray = Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Item Code Number
                [1] => Item Name
                [2] => Item Description
                [3] => MSRP
                [4] => Cost
                [5] => Weight Pounds
                [6] => Weight Kgs
                [7] => Category 1
                [8] => Category 2
                [9] => Category 3
                [10] => Category 4
                [11] => Youtube Link
                [12] => Large Image URL
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => Amazing Magic Set
                [2] => Easy to learn magic tricks
                [3] => 24.95
                [4] => 10.5
                [5] => 0.95
                [6] => 0.43
                [7] => New Items
                [8] => Tricks
                [9] => *New Tricks*
                [10] => All Tricks
                [11] => blank
                [12] => http://www.magicmakersinc.com/images/product/large/0051.jpg
            )
    )
```

You can see the content using a couple of foreach

```
  foreach($myArray as $key1 => $value1){

    foreach( $value1 as $key2 => $value2 ){
      echo  $key1 .  ' ' $key2 .'  value ' .$value2
    }

  }
```

or for specific access to  0, 1, 2, 4, 6

```
  foreach($myArray as $key1 => $value1){

      echo  $key1 .  ' ' . $value1[0]  . '</br>';
      echo  $key1 .  ' ' . $value1[1]  . '</br>';

      echo  $key1 .  ' ' . $value1[2]  . '</br>';
      echo  $key1 .  ' ' . $value1[4]  . '</br>';

      echo  $key1 .  ' ' . $value1[6]  . '</br>';


    }

  }
```

Comment: Where does this specifically show cells 0, 1, 2, 4, 6 ?

Comment: This outputs:    0 I 0 t 0 e 0 0 o       I can't figure out why.

Comment: could be that your array is not like in sample

Answer (score 0):

Something different approach, Combining array together 1st as key, 2nd as value.

```
//$data is contains your multidimensional array!
$combinedData = array_combine($data[0],$data[1]);
```

Now access.... Like!

```
echo $combinedData["Item Code Number"] ; // output 1
echo $combinedData["Item Name"]; //output Amazing Magic Set

//And so on....
```